# Python: Tell BeatifulSoup to choose one value from two

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a value using BeautifulSoup, however the output gives me two values because it is twice on the page, how do I choose one of them? This is my code:

```
url = 'URL'
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("input", {'name': 'CsrfToken', 'type':'hidden'})

for data in data:
    print(data.get('value'))

Output: 
c8b3226dc829256687cac584a9421e8acc4649ff4ee5f8f386ea11ce03a811c8
c8b3226dc829256687cac584a9421e8acc4649ff4ee5f8f386ea11ce03a811c8

The first 'CsrfToken' is in: 
<form method="post" data-url="url" id="test-form" data-test-form="" action="url" name="test-form"><input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="c8b3226dc829256687cac584a9421e8acc4649ff4ee5f8f386ea11ce03a811c8">

The second 'CsrfToken' is in:
<form method="post" name="AnotherForm" class="th-form th-form__compact th-form__compact__inline" data-testid="th-comp-Another-form" action="url" id="AnotherForm"><input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="c8b3226dc829256687cac584a9421e8acc4649ff4ee5f8f386ea11ce03a811c8">
```

I only want the first or second value so that my payload request can load correctly.

Comment: `soup.find` instead of `soup.find_all`?

Comment: Which one would you like to choose? You're the programmer - you have to tell the computer what you want it to do.

Comment: soup.find doesnt work, it gives me no value.

And lets say I want the first value from test-form

Comment: What's wrong using `d = data[0]` ?

Comment: with d = data[0] I get error; ' return self.attrs[key]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()`, it will give you the first instance of the tag on the page.
`find_all()` returns *all* instances of the tag on the page.

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) regarding `find_all()` vs. `find()`:

> The `find_all()` method scans the entire document looking for results,
>   but sometimes you only want to find one result. If you know a document
>   only has one `<body>` tag, it’s a waste of time to scan the entire
>   document looking for more. Rather than passing in `limit=1` every time
>   you call `find_all`, you can use the `find()` method.

So you could still use `find_all()`, just pass in 1 as the limit parameter.

Comment: With find() it doesnt print any value

Comment: Because `find_all()` returns a list of values whereas `find()` returns the value itself

Comment: What does `find("input")` return?

Answer (score 0):

To leave the loop early try:

```
for data in data:
    print(data.get('value'))
    break
```

To always get the first element you can do:

```
def get_first_value(item):
    try:
        return item.get('value')[0]
    except TypeError:
        return None

value = get_first_value(data)
```

Comment: Isn't `find_all` the issue?

Comment: That works, however how would I put that into a payload request, so for example I have:
payload = {
    'CsrfToken':data.get('value')